# operator >> and << not recognized

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am very new to c++ and trying to get a hang of it. The following code is an exact copy of a tutorial where the code works for the tutor. But my IDE (Visual Studio) returns error saying:

```
Error: No operator ">>" matches these operands. 
Error: No operator "<<" matches these operands.
```

What am I missing?

**My Code**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Enter you name" << flush;

    string input;
    cin >> input; //Error as above message

    cout << "your name is " << input << endl; //Error message on the << operator before input

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are missing to do **#include <string>**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not do this:

`#include <string>`

If you're using `std::string`, then you should always #include `<string>`.

Also, I took your code and compiled it using Visual Studio 2013 without the `<string>` header included.  Here is the error:

> error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: His code does fine as it is. So something else is the issue.

Comment: His code is *not* fine.  The `operator >>` and `operator <<` definitions for `std::string` are more than likely implemented in the `<string>` header, which the OP did not include.

Comment: @Thomaschristensen How does this code do fine as is? He is using std::string without including <string>.

Comment: I compiled it by copy and paste from his question and it works (g++ 5.2.1).

Comment: This does solve the problem but the tutorial didn't need this header to work.

Comment: The tutorial is **wrong**.  You need that header as stated in my answer.  If you're using `std::string` and do not include the header, then there is no guarantee that the program will compile successfully.  To guarantee a successful compilation, you have to include the appropriate headers.  This does not only go for `string`, but for any definition your program plans to use.  For example, If I need to use `FILE` and I fail to include `<stdio.h>`, then I can't guarantee that the program will compile successfully for all instances.

Comment: @JasSy Many standard c++ headers include others, but that's totally implementation defined. So you can't rely on such behavior. Always include every standard header you're using declarations from.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So GCC includes `<string>` behind the scene?

Comment: @ThomasChristensen -- That could be the case.  If you open up GCC's `iostream` header, does it include `<string>` anywhere?  I don't know.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Not in itself. I traced back one more step and didn't find any `<string>` include. This doesn't mean that it's not included at a deeper level, but the files to look through grow exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, I was wrong, check the other answer. I was tricked by g++ saying that the code was fine, since as @Joachim said; it might be that `iostream` included by itself `string`.

---

The code is fine. Check your installation, make sure the C++ compiler is installed.

---

As @FrozenKiwi said:

> by default, the C++ compiler is not installed in the last few versions of Visual Studio. You need to modify the installation to ensure the compilers are installed (ie, start -> "Change or Remove a program" -> Visual Studio -> Change

Comment: Just to add to this - by default, the C++ compiler is not installed in the last few versions of Visual Studio.  You need to modify the installation to ensure the compilers are installed (ie, start -> "Change or Remove a program" -> Visual Studio -> Change